# Motion of blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image: enter link description here]

I've been given the value of $F=mg/2$. And I need to find the acceleration of block 2. First I need to know why would the block 2 even move? It should be stationary according to me. I know I'm wrong I just need an explanation.

Comment: Are the blocks stuck together or is friction present?

Comment: Is there a problem description or diagram somewhere that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The forces acting on the pulley are $F_x=\frac{mg}{2}$ and $F_y=mg$. These must be counteracted by the pulley and the box. The vertical force is further counteracted by the normal force acting on box 2, but as there is no friction (I assume) the horizontal force results in the box 2 starting to move.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think block 2 should **not** move?

Assuming the pulley is frictionless, the tension in the string on either side of it must be the same : $T=F=\frac12mg$. So the forces on the pulley are $F_x=\frac12mg$ horizontal to the right and $F_y=\frac12mg$ vertically down.

The acceleration of block 2 depends on what friction there is between it and the ground. If none then the net force on it is $F_x$ since it is attached to the pulley. Block 1 remains in contact with block 2 so they are accelerated together by force $F_x$.

If there is friction $\mu$ between block 2 and the ground, the friction force is $\mu N$ where $N=(m_1+m_2)g$ is the normal reaction. This must be subtracted from $F_x$ to get the net force.

Note that, like the normal forces between the 2 blocks, any friction between them is an internal force, acting equally in opposite directions, so this does not increase the normal reaction $N$ between $m_2$ and the ground. This friction force affects how fast $m_1$ accelerates vertically, but it does not affect the horizontal acceleration of the 2 blocks.